# Why does AO bake look like this?

Tags: texture-baking

Why is  the Ambient Occlusion looking like that with those darker lines and splotches?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: I would suspect it's occlusion from other geometry in the file that hasn't been hidden from renders.